# Checking for concavity of multi-variable function

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Check if the function below is concave.

$$f(x,y) = (x-2)(2000+4\sqrt y-20x) - 10000 - y$$

I tried finding the eigenvalue for the Hessian where

$$det(H-\lambda) = det
\begin{pmatrix}
-40-\lambda & \frac{2}{\sqrt y} \\
\frac{2}{\sqrt y} & -\frac{x-2}{y^{3/2}} - \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
= 0
$$
but I got stuck because the eigenvalue is dependent on x and y.

Is there another way to do this, aside from using the definition of concavity?

Comment: This is neither convex nor concave. And since it only takes one counterexample to prove that, just select a particular $x,y$ and compute the eigenvalues of $H$ for that.